# moviepy writing :Does the time taken to build a video depend on model and other parameters

Tags: python-3.x, object, detection, moviepy

So,Recently I was playing with the open sourced code for Udacity's self driving car vehicle detection project.I saw that for some scenarios where the detection and tracking is not accurate,the moviepy module took just a couple of seconds to build the video.Whereas for another case,where the model was more complex and the results proved to be more accurate,moviepy took roughly 5 hours to build that same video.So does the time taken to write a final video for object detection really depend on the model,or is  there something else going on here that I am not aware of